# All records not getting downloaded on download button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

I am trying to download records of gridview that are checked. Gridview contains images as well as data. Data is getting downloaded in excel sheet. Problem is when i check record of the griview to be downloaded. Only the last checked record gets downloaded. All are not getting downloaded. I think I should use an array. But help me do this:

```
   BubnaManager manager = new BubnaManager();
        int count = GridAssigned.Rows.Count;
        var data = (List<ProductImageMapWrapper>)null;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {

            HiddenField ImageId = GridAssigned.Rows[i].FindControl("hdn_id2") as HiddenField;
            int ImId = Convert.ToInt32(ImageId.Value);
            CheckBox chkIDLabel = GridAssigned.Rows[i].FindControl("NewCheckBoxImage") as CheckBox;
            if (chkIDLabel.Checked == true)
            {
                TextBox txtCompany = GridAssigned.Rows[i].FindControl("TextBoxCompany") as TextBox;
                TextBox txtBrand = GridAssigned.Rows[i].FindControl("TextBoxBrand") as TextBox;
                HiddenField hdBrand = GridAssigned.Rows[i].FindControl("newhdBrand") as HiddenField;
                HiddenField hdCompany = GridAssigned.Rows[i].FindControl("newhdCompany") as HiddenField;
                int brandid = bm.getIdbyBrand(txtBrand.Text);
                int CompanyId = bm.getIdbyCompany(txtCompany.Text);
                data = manager.GetSearchResultForAssignedProductImageMap1(ImId, CompanyId, brandid);
            }

        }


if(data.count!=0)
{
// code for downloading
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing something along the lines of :

```
data.add(manager.GetSearchResultForAssignedProductImageMap1(ImId, CompanyId, brandid));
```

Instead of :

```
data = manager.GetSearchResultForAssignedProductImageMap1(ImId, CompanyId, brandid);
```

With your code you are overwriting the `data` variable every time you find a value. You need to add to the list of values instead of overwriting it.